# Smiling Face :relaxed: emoji not displaying in html ☺

Tags: html, unicode, emoji

I am trying to display emojis for a website messenger and all of the emojis display correctly except the [Smiling Face emoji](https://www.iemoji.com/view/emoji/4/smileys-people/smiling-face). 
Whats more bizarre is that I'm working on two websites and in one the emoji displays correctly and not on the other one. (its the same unicode)
When i copy paste this emoji to skype I get ☺ displaying in the computer but on my cell phone skype app it displays the correct emoji so the unicode is correct for sure .

How can i make this emoji display in browser? Does it depend on certain font?

Comment: @TamásBolvári It does although my question is easier to find and has a correctly marked answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i had the same problem and was able to get it to work by setting the following as the font-family.

`font-family: "Noto Color Emoji", "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", Times, Symbola, Aegyptus, Code2000, Code2001, Code2002, Musica, serif, LastResort;`

Comment: I think changing font-weight might also be important `font-weight: 400;` Since having certain values in certain fonts might make it not appear

Answer (score 2):

Instead of ☺ (U+263A), which is *non-fully-qualified*, try to use ☺️ (U+263A U+FE0F) which is a *fully-qualified* emoji sequence (`U+263A WHITE SMILING FACE` followed by `U+FE0F VARIATION SELECTOR-16`).

You can get an exhaustive list of all *fully-qualified* and *non-fully-qualified* emoji sequences in the [emoji-test.txt](https://www.unicode.org/Public/emoji/11.0/emoji-test.txt) data file.

Comment: I copy pasted your second emoji but it changes nothing :/

Comment: The emoji i originally have is displaying in one of the websites so there must be a way to make it display in the other website as well. It even displays on stackoverflow if you mouse over the title of the question in the question list.

Answer (score 1):

So i have no idea why but setting the style property of font-weight to 200 makes the emote display correctly.

```
font-weight: 200;
```

Comment: What font did you use? (What font did the browser actually render?)

Comment: 'San Francisco Text', sans-serif

Comment: It was rendering Helvetica but after i changed the font weight it started rendering Apple Color Emoji

Comment: Make sure to use all the relevant fonts when displaying emojis. Otherwise e.g. in Windows they'll look strange.

Comment: Can you give me a list of all the relevant fonts. Thats exactly what i was asking in this question.

Comment: I would probably refer to the font styles [emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org) is using in their copy/paste box: `font-weight: 400; font-family: apple color emoji,segoe ui emoji,noto color emoji,android emoji,emojisymbols,emojione mozilla,twemoji mozilla,segoe ui symbol`